# Running a java jar from Django with subprocess.run

Tags: java, django, postgresql, subprocess

I am going mad over something that should be very simple.

I have a jar program that needs to read stuff from a database, called from Django. It takes the db connection url as an arg. When I run it in the command line, all's fine:

```
C:\Dev\mcl>java -jar mcl.jar "jdbc:postgresql://<IP:PORT>/DBName?user=<user>&password=<pwd>"
```

However when I run it within Django from a thread, it doesn't find the postgres driver. I use:

```
result = subprocess.run(['java.exe', '-jar', 'mcl.jar', '"jdbc:postgresql://<IP:PORT>/DBName?user=<user>&password=<pwd>"'], cwd=r'C:\\Dev\\mcl', capture_output=True, shell=True, text=True)
```

It doesn't work, I get:
No suitable driver found for "jdbc:postgresql://<IP:PORT>/DBName?user=&password="

I have tried many things, embedding the postgres jar in mcl.jar, changing the arguments in the subprocess.run call but nothing works.

In the java I have tried with and without

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
```

The Java code is:

```
          try {
                mConn = DriverManager.getConnection(mURL);
                mConn.setAutoCommit(true);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Database connection error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                mConn = null;
            }
```

There must be something specific to Django environment, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to make it work by loading configuration from a file and first creating the driver, and then using it to open the connection. See the following code - java side:

```
    protected boolean loadConfiguration() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(CONFIG_FILE)) {
            properties.load(fileInputStream);
            mURL = properties.getProperty("url");
            mUser = properties.getProperty("user");
            mPassword = properties.getProperty("password");
            return connect() != null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            WTrace.errTrace("Error reading config: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return connect() != null;
    }
    
    protected Connection connect() {
        if (mConn == null) {
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.err.println("Cannot load DB driver: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            Properties info = new Properties(); 
            info.put("user", mUser); 
            info.put("password", mPassword);

            Driver driver;
            try {
                driver = DriverManager.getDriver(mURL);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Get DB driver error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                return null;
            }
            try {
                mConn = driver.connect(mURL, info);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.err.println("Connect error: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            System.err.println("Connection: " + mConn == null ? "fail" : "OK");
        }
        return mConn;
    }
```